# Opengl-Generating random points in a specific range

Tags: c, opengl, random

I want to generate random points in a specific range for an opengl program, say points between the coordinates Xmin=200, Xmax = 400 and Ymin= 200 , Ymax = 400.

Actually I am trying to simulate a volcanic eruption in 2D using simple C code and without using any textures(I cannot use textures in my project). 
PS: I Have very basic knowledge about opengl, just a beginner.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I need help generating random points in the range. If I use Rand()%400 I get points from coordinates 0 to 400 but I need them to start from coordinate 200.

Comment: Consider (Range 0->(max-min)) + min...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate randomly distributed points in a range [min, max] one can use the following formula:

```
(rand() % (max- min)) + min
```

The first part generates random numbers in the range [0, max-min] which are then shifted to [min, max] by adding min to it.

Answer (score 1):

Generate random from 0 to 200 and then shift:
`Rand()%201+200`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.